# Diamonds package is being read as vector of 10 characters in R 3.2.2

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

In short, my R program keeps reading in/attaching the infamous diamonds data set as a vector of 10 characters from "a" to "j". In other words, actual data is not being attached. Below is a copy of my workspace:

```
> clearhistory <- function() {
+   write("", file=".blank")
+   loadhistory(".blank")
+   unlink(".blank")
+ }
> library(ggplot2)

Attaching package: ‘ggplot2’

The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

diamonds

> diamonds
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Note: I am working on Windows 10 on a Toshiba laptop

What I've done thus far:

- Went from problem of qplot not working to discovering that diamonds was not being read correctly
- Uninstalled and reinstalled R
- Clear History with function found on stack overflow
- Asked the teaching assistant in the course
- Searched through Google for various wording types of my problem

Comment: remove the `.RData` file that's lying around in your working directory, then restart R?

Comment: Note that you can still access the data by using `ggplot::diamonds`. Also you can use `rm(diamonds)` to remove the vector of letters from your workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `search()` to see the order in which places containing attached objects are searched—places that are higher up on the list will 'mask' access to objects in places lower down.

In this case, ggplot has been attached, but it's below `.GlobalEnv`, so if you refer to `diamonds` and an object with that  name is found in `.GlobalEnv`, R will just return that without checking other places (like ggplot).

As the commenters mentioned, it's likely the you saved the character vector to `diamonds` in a prior session of R, then saved the workplace when you quit. Now, that workplace is getting opened when you start back up. To verify this, type `ls()` when you start R up in this folder but before you load ggplot2. If `diamonds` is already there, delete it first (or, if there's nothing else you value here, delete the hidden `.Rdata` file in this folder, which is what gets restored on startup).

Comment: Thanks for your help!